# MSSQL - Find and Replace text in ALL stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I recently renamed a table in my database. As the result, I need to find and replace the table name in all of the stored procedures in my database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE m.definition Like '%myoldtable%'
 order by OBJECT_NAME desc
```

When I run the script above, I get 230 matches. There are 230 stored procedures in my database that somehow reference that table name. I want to do a massive find and replace from `myoldtable` to `mynewtable`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an SSDT database project in Visual Studio (or another database management tool) - it's fairly simple to import the database objects and refactor the table name, then create a change script to apply to your database(s).  You can then use this project to version control changes to your DB and even integrate with CI/CD.  Here are some links to get you started:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/import-into-a-database-project?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-rename-and-refactoring-to-make-changes-to-your-database-objects?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you. I was thinking something more in line of TSQL script. I ended up doing it the hard way which was to script out the procedures using the "Generate Script" option in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of [third party tool](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-search.aspx), i personally liked it much as it's simple and easy to use, it basically used for search text within actual data of a database.

However, along with that search feature, there is an add-on feature **Safe Rename** which would be available (after the installation) every right-click menu of the object.

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you. I was thinking something more in line of TSQL script. I ended up doing it the hard way which was to script out the procedures using the "Generate Script" option in SSMS.